# Cannot import Css file into my react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to import my CSS file into the JSX file but I am unable to do that.

```js
import React from 'react';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { Icon } from '@twilio/flex-ui';
import { makeInternalCall } from './index';
import '../../styling/theme1.css'; // Here it throws an error
```

I ran this command in terminal **npm install style-loader css-loader --save-dev**

My webpack.config.js

```js
module.exports = (config, { isProd, isDev, isTest }) => {
  /**
   * Customize the webpack by modifying the config object.
   * Consult https://webpack.js.org/configuration for more information
   */
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
  });

  return config;
}
```

[image: File path]

Theme1.css

```css
.root {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.main {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.formControl {
    width: 250px;
}

.boxDialpad {
    border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

.titleAgentDialpad {
    width: 100%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: inherit;
}

.subtitleDialpad {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.buttonAgentDialpad {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.dialPadBtn {
    border-radius: 100px;
    min-width: 0px;
}
```

And I am getting this error when I run my project. And I am getting this error when I run my project.

[image: Error]

Comment: Which file imports the css?

Comment: internalDialpad.jsx